# How to hide keyboard on dialog showing?

Tags: android, dialog, android-softkeyboard

I have a custom dialog with a EditText in it.
When the dialog appear the focus is on the EditText, and the soft keyboard is showing.
How to avoid this?
I tried:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

and

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edittext.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

but they don't work for me. I think these don't work for dialog.

Comment: see my answer and if u find it useful please make it accept and if u have problem relating to dialog i can help.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Have u tried this?I have tested it.It is working.

**change**

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

**To**

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Thanks, It's also working for me like MayCustomDialog.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Comment: how to hide this keyboard when touch outside of Edittext in Custom AlertDialog Builder..? I want this in my fragment.

Answer (score 10):

Go to xml layout and reach the main layout and put the following

```
 android:focusable="true"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```