# How to prevent Soft Keyboard hiding button in custom dialog?

Tags: android

I have a custom dialog like following 
 [image]

When soft keyboard comes it hides the Button like below.

[image]

my code

https://mcaf.ee/9qhnef

How to avoid Submit button being hide?  i have added autoresize and auto pan but no luck so far.

Comment: move whole view inside the scrollview and add this property in scrollview android:isScrollContainer="true"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide keyboard on dialog showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362273/how-to-hide-keyboard-on-dialog-showing)

Answer (score 0):

Add your whole attribute in one Linear Layout  and put in Scroll View. i hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

or in XML you can change this:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: But where exactly in xml? The parent layout or the edit text?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue once when I had to implement a feedback dialog with height matching almost the screen height. You need to add ScrollView to the parent layout of your view in xml file eg.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    //your content View goes here

  </ScroolView>
```

and then after inflating the view in fragment, 
try this on your onCreateView:

```
 getDialog().getWindow()
.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

The SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE does the trick as it does in case of activities when defined in the manifest file . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Update your Linked Xml with below xml its working, i have tested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#1260C5"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:alpha=".85">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alpha=".5"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imgNotificationClose"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtNotification"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="CHANGE PASSWORD"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textSize="36sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:text="Email"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/old_email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:text="Old Password"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_change_edit_password_current_pass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:text="New Password"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_change_edit_password_new_pass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"

                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:gravity="left|center"
                    android:text="Confirm New Password"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password_change_edit_password_confirm_pass"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"

                    android:padding="10dip"
                    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
                    android:paddingRight="30dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_alert"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/password_change_validation_status"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#BEB2D1"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/password_change_btn_password_submit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:paddingRight="30dp"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem and I found out that the problem was because it was Full Screen.  Try to **remove** this (if you have it) from your `styles.xml`:

```
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```