# Stop activity from measuring views

Tags: android, performance, view, android-databinding

I have an activity with a view pager that holds 5 fragments with a tab layout. This is the activity in the manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".advisor.new_visit_report.cereals.activities.NewVisitReportActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_visit_report"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan">
    </activity>
```

Each activity has several views inside. The problem is that when a new dialog shows, the keyboard opens up and all the views are measured again (I watch that in the Android Monitor log cat). That causes the dialog edittext to freeze and the user can't do nothing for about 2-3 seconds. I have tried to change the manifest options but with no luck. Is important to say that a lot of views inside the fragments are using two-way databinding. Anyone has a clue of what's happening?

Comment: Because it's a dialog I think, that you have to do the keyboard hiding programmatically when opening the dialog. Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362273/how-to-hide-keyboard-on-dialog-showing

Comment: I'm not trying to hide the keyboard. The problem is that when the keyboard shows, the views in the fragment are measured again or updated somehow and that freezes the UI