# How to hide keyboard when dialog is open

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, keyboard

HideKeyboard method not working when dialog is open in other cases works fine.

I tried every popular hideKeyboard method on stack non of them works.

```
fun hideKeyboard(activity: Activity) {
    if(activity == null) return
    val imm = activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm?.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.currentFocus?.windowToken, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS)
}
```

I am not getting any error but keyboard won't close.

Comment: does your dialog has edittext?

Comment: It has 2 buttons and 2 AutoCompleteTextViews

Comment: Is keyboard opens when you open dialog then you can try solution provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362273/how-to-hide-keyboard-on-dialog-showing/17362651

Comment: This doesn't work...it says "Unresolved references getWidow()" and if i add this in front dialog.this.getWindow() than it says "the expresion cannot be selecetor"

Comment: I hope you're using AlertDialog then check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void hideKeyboardFrom(Context context, View view) 
{ 
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0); 
}
```

For kotlin

```
fun hideKeyboard(context : Context, view : View) 
{ 
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager 
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0) 
}
```

Comment: What do i need to pass? "This" and ?

Comment: Context & the view of dialog

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AlertDialog then you can do this as below. You can get getWindow() from `alertDialog` object

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: val mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_profile_name_surname_dialog, null)
            val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(mDialogView).setTitle("Change Name and Surname")
            val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()

Comment: mDialogView.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); not working it says "Unresolved references getWidow()"

Comment: use mAlertDialog.getWindow()

Comment: I don't know...i alrdy found solution above

Answer (score 1):

```
HideKeyboard function Android Code
```

public void hideKeyboard(View view, Context context)
{

```
       try {

        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    } catch (Exception Ex) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you will call hide keyboard method.I have show type of hide keyBoard methods given in below.If you want use your like methods.

```
    public void hideKeyboard(View view, Context context) {
            try {
                if (view != null) {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) 
                    context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
            } catch (Exception Ex) {
            }
        }
    
        public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            if (view == null) {
                view = new View(activity);
            }
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
```

2. Then you will call Dialog.

Conclusions first you call hide method and after that Dialog.So When call hide method then hide keyboard and and again calling Dialog after call dialog then open.